# RSpec examples fail differently on different machines

Tags: rspec, raise

**The first one prints error infomations as follow:**

```
Failures:
```

1) UnitShip 测试增删改： Create should be successful
     Failure/Error: unit_ship = UnitShip.create(DataGenerator::Master.unit_ship)
     Psych::SyntaxError:
       couldn't parse YAML at line 14 column 14
     # ./spec/support/data_generator/master.rb:9:in `unit_ship'
     # ./spec/models/unit_ship_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '

2) UnitShip 测试增删改： 删除 should be successful.
     Failure/Error: unit_ship = UnitShip.create(DataGenerator::Master.unit_ship)
     Psych::SyntaxError:
       couldn't parse YAML at line 14 column 14
     # ./spec/support/data_generator/master.rb:9:in `unit_ship'
     # ./spec/models/unit_ship_spec.rb:28:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 1.65 seconds
13 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/unit_ship_spec.rb:7 # UnitShip 测试增删改： Create should be successful
rspec ./spec/models/unit_ship_spec.rb:27 # UnitShip 测试增删改： 删除 should be successful.

**The another prints error infomations as follow:**

```
Failures:
```

1) Unit Update should not be successful
     Failure/Error: @fabric =  FactoryGirl.build(:fabric)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       校验失败: 编号 已经被使用
     # ./spec/models/unit_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in '

2) Unit Destroy should not be successful
     Failure/Error: @fabric =  FactoryGirl.build(:fabric)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       校验失败: 编号 已经被使用
     # ./spec/models/unit_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 1.16 seconds
13 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/unit_spec.rb:21 # Unit Update should not be successful
rspec ./spec/models/unit_spec.rb:36 # Unit Destroy should not be successful

======================================================================
This first one is incorrect, the second one is correct .

why?

please help me . thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the version of the Yaml parser your Ruby is compiled against.

Your second machine is using `Syck`, while your first one is using `Psych`. To force the first one to use `Syck`, put this in your `application.rb`:

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler='syck'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have fixed it by using your method . Thanks again !